# Computing the centre of the Clifford Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, clifford-algebras

I'm currently looking at a $8$-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-algebra denoted either by $C_n$ or $C(a_1, a_2, a_3)$.  After some looking around, I think this is called a Clifford algebra?  If not, I apologise for the incorrect title!

We consider the basis of $C_n$ to be $e_I$, where $I$ ranges over the subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$.  We also have the following rules for multiplication:

1)  $e_\emptyset = 1$

2)  $e_i e_j = - e_j e_i, i \neq j$

3)  $e_i^2 = 1$

I want to show that the centre of $C(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ is isomorphic to a quotient:
$C(a_1, a_2, a_3) \cong \mathbb{R}[T]/(T^2 + a_1a_2a_3)$.

Afterwards, I am meant to generalise this for any $n$.

I feel like I'll be able to generalise for any $n$ once I have done the first part (I am aware that I'll have to look at different cases for values of $n$), but I'm unsure how the actually show this isomorphism!  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a Clifford algebra.  A reference for the proof would be e.g. the first chapter of Friedrich's "Dirac operators in Riemannian geometry."

Answer (score 0):

It's also easily computed from the [structure theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_Clifford_algebras#Classification) for Clifford algebras.

In your particular case, the algebra is isomorphic to $M_2(\Bbb R)\times M_2(\Bbb R)$ whose center is $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$.